# Como juntar 2 tabelas em um select?

Tags: mysql

Galera tenho as seguinte tabelas no meu BD MySQL:

`produtos_pedido` com os seguintes campos

> id,id_pedido,id_produto,qtd

`produtos_troca` com os seguintes campos

> id,id_pedido,id_produto,qtd

Bom preciso fazer um `SELECT` onde me retorne o `id_produto` (com distinct sem repetir o produto) e a `qtd` (total, ou seja somando o qtd dos produtos iguais) porém tenho que juntar as duas tabelas. 
Isso é possível em MySQL?

Alguém poderia me ajudar com este `SELECT`?

Comment: Você quer a quantidade de total dos produtos nas duas tabelas? Ou a quantidade de produtos por pedido/troca?

Comment: a quantidade total dos produtos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se eu percebi bem você quer juntar as duas tabelas e depois selecionar todos os produtos por `id_produto` e somar as quantidades, então será isto:

```
SELECT id_produto, SUM(qtd) as qtdTotal 
FROM (
      SELECT id, id_produto, qtd FROM produtos_pedido 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT id, id_produto, qtd FROM produtos_troca
     ) res 
GROUP BY id_produto;
```

[Veja a funcionar](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30988/2)

Comment: Jorge era isso mesmo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode elaborar da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT 
    pp.id, 
    pp.id_pedido as id_pedido_pedido,
    pt.ltd  as quantidade
FROM produtos_pedido as pp
JOIN produtos_troca as pt USING(id_produto)
```

Quando fizer o `foreach()` você usa o echo `$valor['quantidade']`  pra exibir a quantidade daquele produto.

Comment: ok mas preciso escrever a quantidade e o id, e tem que ter DISTINC e somar as qtd dos produtos iguais

Comment: Então ajuste sua questão, porque da forma que postou não está muito clara.

Comment: ok fis a mudança na pergunta, so agora vi a necessidade do DISTINC. Poderia me ajudar? pois testei aqui e seu select fez o que preciso, so falta o DISTINC e o SUM na qtd.

Answer (score 1):

Se é o que eu entendi bem, você que que seja somado os valores da coluna (qtd), mas que não seja mostrado o mesmo id do produto.

Se for isso você pode usar as funções SUM() para somar os valores, GROUP BY para agrupar os dados.

Assim;

```
SELECT count(pp.id) as id, sum(pt.ltd) as TotalQtd
FROM produtos_pedido as pp
JOIN produtos_troca as pt
group by pp.id
```