# Mysql select mesma coluna de 6 tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho 6 tabelas `MySql` que contém uma coluna DE MESMO NOME  `descricao` (varchar) e gostaria de criar uma nova tabela com os dados desta coluna agrupados (sem repetir).

Gostaria de saber como selecionar o campo "descricao" das tabelas "tabela1", "tabela2","tabela3","tabela4","tabela5","tabela6" e armazenar em uma nova tabela.

Estou usando mysql 8 ou mysql 5.7

Comment: Gostaria de deixar uma reflexão, você realmente necessita realizar o armazenamento de dados duplicados em outra tabela do seu banco de dados? Apesar de isso ser possível, são raros os cenários em que isso se torna viável.

Comment: já tentou algo Eduardo? coloque pra pergunta para podemos seguir o mesmo raciocinio ou ver se só basta algo

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal. Se possível adicione mais informações como nome das tabelas envolvidas, para que facilite adaptar a resposta para a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Da mesma maneira que se é possível realizar um [Select dentro de outro Select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365724/select-dentro-de-select-onde-exista-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o), o `MySql` permite realizar outras operações como um `SELECT` dentro de um `INSERT`.

Supondo que temos 2 tabelas como exemplo, e que gostariamos de realizar um `SELECT` de uma tabela, e realizar um `INSERT` em outra.

- Tabela_A - Colunas: id, titulo, descricao, valor.
- Tabela_B - Colunas: id, descricao

Resultado:

```
INSERT INTO Tabela_B (id, descricao)
SELECT (id, descricao) from Tabela_A;
```

Como o seu cenário, necessita de fazer [select em mais de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147333/como-juntar-2-tabelas-em-um-select), você pode, simplesmente fazer o insert, do resultado da UNION das duas tabelas.

```
INSERT INTO Tabela_B (..., ...)
(SELECT (..., ...) from TABELA_A
UNION
SELECT (..., ...) from TABELA_C);
```

Comment: Realizada a correção, para se adaptar a pergunta (sem repetir).

Comment: Usar o UNION me retorna erro de SQL:

`INSERT INTO tabela_resultado (descricao) 
(SELECT (descricao) from tabela_A
union 
SELECT (descricao) from tabela_B);`

Comment: Isso provavelmente ocorra pois o nome de suas tabelas não são ```Tabela_A```, e  ```Tabela_B```, você deverá fazer o ajuste de acordo com o nome de suas tabelas.

Comment: Claro que os nomes descritos são fictícios @vitor-subhi